# Thermostat seven segment

Tags: c++, arduino, atmega

I am building a thermostat with arduino mega 2560.I would like to adjust the desired temperature and present it at two seperate seven segment displays. My problem is that it doesn't work.I think the problem is that when I call the function.I would like someone to help me with this project please.
Here is my void loop code

````
void loop() {
  buttonStateP = digitalRead(buttonPinP);

  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDR);
  Wire.write(0x3B); // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) [MPU-6000 and MPU-6050 Register Map and Descriptions Revision 4.2, p.40]
  Wire.endTransmission(false); // the parameter indicates that the Arduino will send a restart. As a result, the connection is kept active.
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_ADDR, 7*2, true); // request a total of 7*2=14 registers

  // "Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();" means two registers are read and stored in the same variable
  accelerometer_x = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) and 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
  accelerometer_y = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) and 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  accelerometer_z = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) and 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  temperature = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) and 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  gyro_x = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) and 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  gyro_y = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) and 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  gyro_z = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) and 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)





  // print out data
  //Serial.print("aX = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(accelerometer_x));
 // Serial.print(" | aY = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(accelerometer_y));
 // Serial.print(" | aZ = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(accelerometer_z));
  // the following equation was taken from the documentation [MPU-6000/MPU-6050 Register Map and Description, p.30]
  //Serial.print(" | tmp = "); Serial.println(temperature/340.00+36.53);
 // Serial.print(" |      |"); Serial.print(counter);
 // Serial.print(" | gX = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(gyro_x));
 // Serial.print(" | gY = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(gyro_y));
 // Serial.print(" | gZ = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(gyro_z));
 // Serial.println();
  // delay
 delay(1000);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonStateP != lastButtonStateP) {
    // if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (buttonStateP == LOW) {
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
      bPress = true;
      buttonPushCounterP++;
      if( buttonPushCounterP > 99) buttonPushCounterP =0 ;
      Serial.println("buttonPushCounterP");

    } else {
      // if the current state is LOW then the button went from on to off:
      Serial.println("off");
    }
    // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
    delay(50);
  }
 // save the current state as the last state, for next time through the loop
  lastButtonStateP = buttonStateP;

  if( bPress ){
     turnOff();

  }


if (buttonPushCounterP = 0){

  zero1();
  zero2();
  }





dt = temperature;
 if (buttonPushCounterP < dt){
  analogWrite(ledON,1000);
}
 else if(buttonPushCounterP > dt){
  analogWrite(ledON,0);
}

}
void turnOff()
{
  digitalWrite(Aa,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Ba,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(E1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(F1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G1,LOW);

  digitalWrite(Ab,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Bb,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(E2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(F2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G2,LOW);
}```
````

Comment: Post all the code.  Take out all the lines that are commented out.  I don't see anywhere in this code where you try to do anything with any 7 segment display.

Comment: I use 2 7seg displays.2 buttons to increase and decrease the desired temperature and a 6dof sensor with temp sensor"i use it only as a temperature sensor".

Answer (score 0):

````
#include "Wire.h" // This library allows you to communicate with I2C devices.

const int MPU_ADDR = 0x68; // I2C address of the MPU-6050. If AD0 pin is set to HIGH, the I2C address will be 0x69.

int16_t accelerometer_x, accelerometer_y, accelerometer_z; // variables for accelerometer raw data
int16_t gyro_x, gyro_y, gyro_z; // variables for gyro raw data
int16_t temperature; // variables for temperature data

const int E1 = 22;
const int D1 = 23;
const int C1 = 24;
const int Ba = 25;
const int Aa = 26;
const int F1 = 27;
const int G1 = 28;

const int E2 = 29;
const int D2 = 30;
const int C2 = 31;
const int Bb = 32;
const int Ab = 33;
const int F2 = 34;
const int G2 = 35;


int ledPOWER = 3;
int ledON = 2;

bool bPress = false;
const int buttonPinP = 12;
int dt = 0;


// Variables will change:
int buttonPushCounterP = 0;   // counter for the number of button presses
int buttonStateP = 0;         // current state of the button
int lastButtonStateP = 0;     // previous state of the button


char tmp_str[7]; // temporary variable used in convert function

char* convert_int16_to_str(int16_t i) { // converts int16 to string. Moreover, resulting strings will have the same length in the debug monitor.
  sprintf(tmp_str, "%6d", i);
  return tmp_str;
}
void zero1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ba,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Aa,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G1,LOW);  
}

void one1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ba,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Aa,LOW);
  digitalWrite(F1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G1,LOW);  
}

void two1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Ba,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Aa,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G1,HIGH);  
}

void three1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ba,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Aa,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G1,HIGH);  
}

void four1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ba,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Aa,LOW);
  digitalWrite(F1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G1,HIGH);  
}

void five1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ba,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Aa,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G1,HIGH);  
}

void six1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ba,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Aa,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G1,HIGH);  
}

void seven1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ba,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Aa,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G1,LOW);  
}

void eight1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ba,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Aa,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G1,HIGH);  
}

void nine1(){
  digitalWrite(E1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ba,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Aa,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G1,HIGH);  
}


//2nd seg
void zero2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Bb,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ab,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G2,LOW);  
}

void one2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Bb,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ab,LOW);
  digitalWrite(F2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G2,LOW);  
}

void two2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Bb,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ab,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G2,HIGH);  
}

void three2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Bb,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ab,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G2,HIGH);  
}

void four2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Bb,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ab,LOW);
  digitalWrite(F2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G2,HIGH);  
}

void five2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Bb,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Ab,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G2,HIGH);  
}

void six2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Bb,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Ab,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G2,HIGH);  
}

void seven2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Bb,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ab,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G2,LOW);  
}

void eight2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Bb,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ab,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G2,HIGH);  
}

void nine2(){
  digitalWrite(E2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Bb,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Ab,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G2,HIGH);  
}



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDR); // Begins a transmission to the I2C slave (GY-521 board)
  Wire.write(0x6B); // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0); // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);

  analogWrite(ledPOWER,1000);



  pinMode(E1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Ba,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Aa,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(F1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(G1,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(E2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Bb,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Ab,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(F2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(G2,OUTPUT);

  pinMode( buttonPinP , INPUT_PULLUP );


}

void loop() {
  buttonStateP = digitalRead(buttonPinP);

  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_ADDR);
  Wire.write(0x3B); // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) [MPU-6000 and MPU-6050 Register Map and Descriptions Revision 4.2, p.40]
  Wire.endTransmission(false); // the parameter indicates that the Arduino will send a restart. As a result, the connection is kept active.
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_ADDR, 7*2, true); // request a total of 7*2=14 registers

  // "Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read();" means two registers are read and stored in the same variable
  accelerometer_x = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) and 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
  accelerometer_y = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) and 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  accelerometer_z = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) and 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  temperature = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) and 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  gyro_x = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) and 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  gyro_y = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) and 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  gyro_z = Wire.read()<<8 | Wire.read(); // reading registers: 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) and 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)





  // print out data
  //Serial.print("aX = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(accelerometer_x));
 // Serial.print(" | aY = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(accelerometer_y));
 // Serial.print(" | aZ = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(accelerometer_z));
  // the following equation was taken from the documentation [MPU-6000/MPU-6050 Register Map and Description, p.30]
  //Serial.print(" | tmp = "); Serial.println(temperature/340.00+36.53);
 // Serial.print(" |      |"); Serial.print(counter);
 // Serial.print(" | gX = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(gyro_x));
 // Serial.print(" | gY = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(gyro_y));
 // Serial.print(" | gZ = "); Serial.print(convert_int16_to_str(gyro_z));
 // Serial.println();
  // delay
 delay(1000);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonStateP != lastButtonStateP) {
    // if the state has changed, increment the counter
    if (buttonStateP == LOW) {
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
      bPress = true;
      buttonPushCounterP++;
      if( buttonPushCounterP > 99) buttonPushCounterP =0 ;
      Serial.println("buttonPushCounterP");

    } else {
      // if the current state is LOW then the button went from on to off:
      Serial.println("off");
    }
    // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
    delay(50);
  }
 // save the current state as the last state, for next time through the loop
  lastButtonStateP = buttonStateP;

  if( bPress ){
     turnOff();

  }


if (buttonPushCounterP = 0){

  zero1();
  zero2();
  }





dt = temperature;
 if (buttonPushCounterP < dt){
  analogWrite(ledON,1000);
}
 else if(buttonPushCounterP > dt){
  analogWrite(ledON,0);
}

}
void turnOff()
{
  digitalWrite(Aa,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Ba,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(E1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(F1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G1,LOW);

  digitalWrite(Ab,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Bb,LOW);
  digitalWrite(C2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(D2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(E2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(F2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G2,LOW);
}```
````